# How to cancel a drag (on dragenter)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm on classic javascript and i want to cancel a drag on enter in a specific div.

in HTML :

```
<!-- Element i want to drag -->
<div id="draggableElement" draggable="true"></div>

<!-- Element which cancels the drag on enter -->
<div id="specificDiv"></div>
```

in JS :

```
document.addEventListener("dragenter", event=> {
    if (event.target.id == "specificDiv") {
        // Cancel the drag
    }
}, false);
```

I already search on the web but i didn't find a solution, however i found some js libraries but it's too much for the only thing i want to do.

Thanks by advance.

***EDIT :***

More precisly i want, at least, undisplay the draged image by entering in my specific div to see this one.

So i've already tried to hide the draged image but it doesn't work on dragenter (only in dragstart).

in JS :

```
let dragged;

document.addEventListener("dragstart", event=> {
    dragged = event;
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragenter", event=> {
    if (event.target.id == "specificDiv") {
        // Hide the dragged image or cancel the drag
        event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(new Image(), 0, 0); // Doesn't work
        dragged.dataTransfer.setDragImage(new Image(), 0, 0); // Doesn't work too
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Why dont you just remove the dragstart listener when dragenter listener is fired?

Comment: @abhishekkhandait, i tried today but it doesn't work.

Comment: ok Ill give it a try and come up with a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so you want to hide the dragged element when enters over renderCanvas but WITHOUT releasing mouse button am I right?

If so, you have to know that is not possible to modifying drag-ghost-image without releasing mouse button. In that case you can simulate a custom Drag&Drop and hide the dragged element when its position is in range with the other element:

```js
let specificDiv = document.getElementById('specificDiv');
let renderCanvas = document.getElementById('renderCanvas');

//Catches target position
rect = renderCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
rectX = rect.left;
rectY = rect.top;

//Release dragged element
let released;
document.addEventListener('mouseup', ()=>{
    released = true;
})

//Drag element
specificDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', (ev) => {
    released = false;
    specificDiv.addEventListener('mousemove', (e)=>{
        if(!released) {
            //Collects actual mouse position while dragging
            x = e.clientX
            y = e.clientY
            
            //Moves dragged element
            specificDiv.style.left = (x-80) + 'px';
            specificDiv.style.top = (y-80) + 'px';

            //Hides dragged element when is over the other
            if(y > rectY) {
                specificDiv.style.opacity="0"
            }
        }
    })
})
```

```css
#specificDiv {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
}

#renderCanvas {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 20em;
    width: 20em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Div element you want to drag-->
    <div id="specificDiv">DRAGGED ELEMENT</div>
    <!-- Div element who cancels the drag on enter -->
    <div id="renderCanvas">TARGET ELEMENT</div>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll have to adapt rectX and rectY to your specific divs position.

Comment: does it work for you? in a sense it works because after the drop the element that I want to drag is not draggable anymore but it does not undisplay the dragged image

Comment: I've reformuled the solution creating a custom D&D. Please check it if it works for your project

Comment: yep, it's a solution and it works, i just need to adpat it a bit to re display the specific div on "dragend" and to get informations of the dragged element but it will be alright, thanks for your help !!!

Answer (score 1):

The following would be a solution to allow dropping on a div and on another div don't allow dropping:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

const target = document.querySelector("#dragtarget");
const notarget = document.querySelector("#nodragtarget");
const dragged = document.querySelector("#dragitem");

target.addEventListener("dragover", allowDrop);

target.addEventListener("drop", drop);

dragged.addEventListener("dragstart", drag)
```

```css
div[draggable] {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background: yellow;
}

div#dragtarget {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

div#nodragtarget {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="dragitem" draggable="true"></div>
<div id="dragtarget"></div>
<div id="nodragtarget"></div>
```

Comment: it not a solution for me, but thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

did my answer worked for you? I am quite curious